# Java/C Ternary Operator

Tags: java, c, conditional-statements

i want to transform a code from if condition to a ternary condition, 
first i've succeeded to transform one condition like:

```
    int minutes=59,hours=23;
// 1) if condition
if (minutes<59)
    minutes++;
else
    minutes=0;

// 2) ternary condition
minutes = (minutes < 59) ? minutes+1  :  0;
```

Now the problem is when i've more than one value to edit it, like:

```
    int minutes=59,hours=23;
// if condition
if (minutes<59)
    minutes++;
else
{
    minutes = 0;
    if (hours<23)
        hours++;
    else 
        hours=0;
}
```

what do you think about the ternary condition ?
thanks :)

Comment: Just as a tip, ternary conditions are harder to read. I recommend you keep the if statements.

Comment: For what you are trying to do, I would use the modulus operator.  minutes = (minutes + 1) % 60 and hours = (hours + 1) % 24 are quite readable and concise.

Comment: Yes, please don't.  Storage is cheap.  You can afford to store readable code.

Comment: they are rarely harder to read.

Comment: I think that, at least for simple assignments, ternary operations are easier to read, and obviously more concise (of course, that's not always a good thing).

Comment: I use ternary operators only if the second and third components are extremely simple (ie a single variable or constant value), and even then I use them sparingly.  There's nothing wrong with writing readable code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I think about it is that you shouldn't do it.

But if you really want to, you can write this:

```
minutes = (minutes < 59)
        ? (minutes+1)
        : ((hours = (hours < 23) ? (hours+1) : 0), 0);
```

**But don't.**

Comment: `minutes=(minutes<59)?(minutes+1):((hours=(hours<23)?(hours+1):0),0);` It's better on one line with no whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

"[Don't do that, then.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/Don-t-do-that-then-.html)"

It isn't appropriate, or even *possible*, to transform all if-then constructs to `?:` constructs, in either Java or C.  (It *is* possible in functional languages, but even then it is not always advised.)

For what you appear to be trying to do, I would write

```
minutes++;
if (minutes == 60) { minutes = 0; hours++; }
if (hours == 24)   { hours = 0;   days++;  }
// etcetera
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ternary conditions are painful! Just don't...

Not sure what you're trying to do but if need to round dates you might want to take a look at `DateUtils` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I think my preferred way to do this would be

```
minutes = minutes == 59 ? 0 : minutes + 1;
if (minutes == 0) {
    hours = hours == 23 ? 0 : hours + 1;
}
```

You avoid the readability problems of the nested ifs, but don't have a crazy ternary statement.  The best balance between concision and readability, I think.

Comment: + I agree that it is a nice balance, although I would add () around the conditional statement for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Though the ternary operator is a nice shorthand when you would like to embed a conditional into a larger expression, it's not good to overuse it.  It can make things less readable and doesn't necessarily speed up your code.  However...

You can use the comma operator to combine expressions (the value will be that of the last one).  Your example could be rewritten as follows:

```
minutes = (minutes < 59) ? 
    minutes + 1 : 
    ( hours < 23 ? 
        (hours++, 0) : 
        (hours = 0) );
```

Though for the example you gave, using the modulus operator for `hours` could simplify it as follows:

```
hours = (minutes = (minutes + 1) % 60) ? hours : ((hours + 1) % 24);
```

..since the result of an assignment is the value assigned in C, and you can use that as your test expression.

This works for C... not sure about Java.